# what's wrong with this c codes?

Tags: c, dev-c++

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int i = 1;
    int j = -1;

    while(i)
        i++;
    while(-j)
        j--;

    i = i-1;
    j = j+1;

    printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
}
```

I want to know the range of int!  this code can not get the right answer! But it can!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int i = 1;
    int j = -1;

    while(i > 0)
        i++;
    while(j < 0)
        j--;

    i = i-1;
    j = j+1;

    printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
}
```

I don't know what are the differences between them!

Answer (score 5):

Both of these code samples rely on undefined behavior to determine the maximum value of an int. Overflow is not defined for a signed number like `int`.

To find the maximum value of an int, you simply read the value [`INT_MAX`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits).

If you truly want to calculate the value of [`INT_MAX`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) in a portable way, then you should look into this answer: [Is there a portable way to define INT_MAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800767/is-there-a-portable-way-to-define-int-max)

Comment: I missed the main problem. +1 BTW

Answer (score 4):

Try `limits.h` from the standard C library. It contains the two constant definitions `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`, telling you the minimum and maximum values of an `int` respectively.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("int min: %d, int max: %d\n", INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to know the range of `int`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d, %d\n", INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
-2147483648, 2147483647
```

And following the answer from @iharob, here is a similar solution that reaches the limit without UB.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int integer = -1, max = 0;
    while (integer <<= 1)
        max = (max << 1) | 1;
    printf("%d\n", max);
    return 0;
}
```

Lastly, a niftier solution (no loops) would be

```
printf("Max int %d\n", (unsigned)-1 >> 1);
```

Comment: 2nd approach is nifty!  Works well for 2's complement.  For uncommon sign magnitude and 1's complement, start with `max = 1`.

Comment: 1 up-vote for nice answer

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to compute the value, you can use this

```
int
main(int arcg, char **argv)
{
    int integer;
    int i;

    integer = 0;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 8 * sizeof (integer) - 1 ; i++)
    {
        integer |= (1 << i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and then the maximum will be `integer` and the minimum will be `-integer`

Comment: 1) Far more common minimum will be `-integer - 1`.  2) An example of this approach [without a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17801237/2410359)

Comment: This assumes that a `char` is always eight bits in size. You should use `CHAR_BIT` instead.